# List of Figures/List of Tables not compiling - Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to create the list of figures and list of tables necessary for my thesis. Unfortunately both refuse to work. I can compile the latex first time, which inserts an empty List of Figures. But upon second compilation, that list refuses to populate and the document will not compile.

The error I get is the following:

```
/Thesis.lot.4:Undefined control sequence.
\l@table #1#2->\ifnum \c@lotdepth
```

See below for an image of the output.

[image: Error output]

This error persists for every single table within the thesis, so I think this is a general issue, not a local problem.

The table code looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
\textbf{Country of Residence} & \textbf{Number of Participants} \\ \midrule
United Kingdom                & 94                              \\ 
...
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Countries of residence...}
\label{tab:Residence}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I'm aware the error message and table code I have posted may not be enough, but I am genuinely stumped as to where this error might be coming from. A similar message appears when I attempt the list of figures. If you would like to see any more code then please do let me know.

I could not seem to see this issue elsewhere (without it being fixed by a simple TrashAux, something which will not work in this situation).

Thanks very much for any help.

### Edits

Document class is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
```

Comment: floats like figures and tables are defined (or not) by the document class. You've given no indication which class you are using so it is hard to help.

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing that out. Have added to the post now. It's \documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}

Comment: every question should really have a _complete small_ document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem. It looks like your aux file is using `tocloft` package which hasn't been loaded, or used incorrectly or...

Comment: @SarahW: Please click on the link to see what is meant by a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: have you tried simply deleting the `.lot` file?

Comment: I have tried deleting the files created during the process, such as the .lot file but this does not seem to fix the issue. I am really unsure of how to create a MWE in this instance, as a small toy example compiles correctly. I would like to be able to replicate it but can't at the moment. I suppose I was hoping that there might be a common issue that causes this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely you are using package `tocloft` with option `subfigure`. In this case `tocloft` assumes you have loaded package `subfigure` (or its successor `subfig`), which would have defined counter `lotdepth` (and `lofdepth`). But the latter package is not loaded apparently, thus the counter is not defined and you see the error message because of its usage.

Either remove option `subfigure` from `tocloft`:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

Then the counters are defined by package `tocloft`. Or load `subfig`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Hello}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This has solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}\hline
\textbf{Country of Residence} & \textbf{Number of Participants} \\hline 
United Kingdom                & 94                              \ \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Countries of residence...}
\label{tab:Residence}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
% I have made it simple. No need to add midrule and bottomrule. Just \hline will do

Comment: Please explain how removing the horizontal lines from booktabs in the table solves the problem that was related to options of the tocloft package?